# Javascript jQuery Event Performance MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, javascriptmvc, spine.js

I was reviewing a Javascript application for performance, the application is built with spine.js and underscore js (acting as template engine). There is one common EventManager.js which handles all events in the application (by jQuery 'on' event handling on body element, please see the snippet below) and then application has its own publish subscribe mediator delegation to all the modules, it filters the events and then sends to all modules, by filtering the target and publishes internal event to module.

Event for a mouse move the event is being handled on the event manager, so any mouse move will be handled by the event manager instead of just handling mouse move on a specific div element. I think there is too many functions going on.

For example: the click event on a div is handled by module like `module.subscribe("App-Click", onModuleClickHandler, filter: { selector: '#someSelector')`. if that selector is clicked then `eventmanager` checks if the current target has that selector, then it publishes the custom "App-Click" to that module.

Is it good to handle like this or just handle on the submodule with the events on them for each html instead of common event manager? Please comment if any part of the question is vague and I will update that part in more detail.

The following is the snippet of `eventManager`:

```
$('body')
    .on('mousedown',   onMouseEvent)
    .on('mouseup',     onMouseEvent)
    .on('mouseover',   onMouseEvent)
    .on('mousemove',   onMouseEvent)
    .on('mouseout',    onMouseEvent)
    .on('click',       onMouseEvent)
    .on('mousewheel',  onMouseWheelEvent);
```

Comment: You should only ask for events for those that you're interested in.

Comment: @LeeTaylor The application needs all these events, do you mean registering on specific div instead of dom? ($('#divid').on) instead of body.Also, how can I measure the performace of both and tell them this is bad on performance vs this is good.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was you should only ask for those events for the specific DOM elements you need them for. You can use the built in profiler tools in modern browsers to help you determine the performance gains to be made

Answer (score 0):

Event propagation on DOM uses [sinking/bubbling](http://catcode.com/domcontent/events/capture.html) with sinking(capture) and bubbling phases.
Your event manager shall in principle implement this too as it quite flexible and practical.

But it is not clear why would you need to implement this by your own. It is there already.

Comment: The application did not implement event propogation, but they have created a mvc architecture so that the dom events  are handled in the eventmanager.js and then send to only modules which have subscribe to a custom event name corresponding to that dom event, for example: the click event on a div is handled by module like module.subscribe("App-Click", onModuleClickHandler, filter: { selector: '#someSelector'). if that selector is clicked then eventmanager publishes the custom "App-Click" to that module. I donot know why they have done like this, just want to know pros and cons of this.